# Why is Time doing strange things when converted to long? Java

Tags: java, time, long-integer

```
Time t = Time.valueOf("00:00:00");
long l = t.getTime(); // why is l -3600000
```

I would like to convert my time values to seconds in order to do addition and substraction operations.

Comment: "I would like to convert my time values to seconds in order to do addition and substraction operations." Don't. Use the APIs.

Comment: Stop using Time. It's for SQL, has a broken design, and always uses default time zone. Use java.time.LocalTime. And use its API rather than transforming to seconds.

Comment: But as to your specific question: are you in London, by any chance? Or, at least, using `Europe/London` as your time zone?

Comment: Most date/time APIs have a concept of a anchor point - a point in time from which all other operations are calculated.  This makes these objects simply containers for the amount of time from the anchor point to the point they represent (in the case of Java, the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running this code in the UK. Or at least, on a JVM whose default time zone is `Europe/London`. Or at least a time zone that was 1 hour ahead of UTC at Unix epoch.

[Here's an Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/n2fQ3d).

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    Time t = Time.valueOf("00:00:00");
    long l = t.getTime(); // why is l -3600000
    System.out.println(l);
```

The reason is that London was in permanent daylight savings at Unix epoch, so the actual time of epoch in London is 1970/1/1 01:00:00.

As such, 1970/1/1 00:00:00 in that time zone is 60 minutes (or 3600000 milliseconds) before epoch.

[Here's a fork of the same demo, setting the timezone to UTC](https://ideone.com/U3AWUk). This prints zero.

Comment: my problem was resolved by using LocalTime. You've addressed the root cause hence answer being accepted.